# REST Api Authentication per users in App

Tags: rest

I am creating a REST API server. For each app I have provided API key and secret. Example apps are Web app, mobile app any other app who want to use my api service. Now my API service will also need user authentication. How do I implement that? I have already done app authentication using hmac signature generation. Now I need help on implementing user authentication on those apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend you use OAuth or OAuth2 concept because it's standardized and widely adopted. You will be also able allow users to login with Facebook, Google account, etc.